# Energy Conservation for STFT

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

The project I am working on requires a short-time Fourier transformation. For this, I use scipy.signal.stft. From theory, we learn that the signal in time domain has the same energy as in time-frequency domain; Parseval's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem). However, when I use scipy.signal.stft, I do not obtain the same amount of energy if I compare the computation for both values of energy. I am pretty sure, it is because there is some scaling involved when using scipy.signal.stft, so I spit through the source code. After some deep search, I have found a scaling factor of np.sqrt(1/(sum(win)**2)). However, using this scaling factor, does not work:

Example code:

```
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 500*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.25*time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*3e3*time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power),
                         size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time/5)
x = carrier + noise

frame_size = 1000
window = scipy.signal.windows.hann(frame_size,sym=False)
f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(x, fs, window=window, nperseg=frame_size)
scale = np.sqrt(1/(sum(window)**2))
Zxx_scaled = Zxx/scale

Et=np.sum(x**2)
Ef=np.sum(abs(Zxx_scaled)**2)/N
print("Et = %.3f" % Et)
print( "Ef = %.3f" % Ef)
```

results in (depending on noise, but in the scale of):

```
Et = 1641328.607
Ef = 6158.539
```

Does anyone know how to properly scale the resulting STFT matrix values to obtain equal energy levels and prove energy conservation for the STFT?

(I am looking for a `sum(window)**2` constant transformation (and window) and, as the window is used in the STFT and I-STFT, I assume I have a 'tight frame' transformation if I use the hann window. However, proving energy conservation is a first step.....)